# Basic Java program giving wrong ouput

Tags: java

I'm getting just spaces after running this code, it is not even printing `"ABC"`..

```
import java.io.*;
class Str{
  public static void main( String args[])
  {
    String a = "abc";
    char ch[] = new char[2];
    a.getChars(0,0,ch,1);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    pw.println(ch);
    pw.println("ABC");
    pw.println(ch);
    System.out.println(ch);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getChars uses parameters (int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char[] dest, int destBegin). Your srcBegin and srcEnd are both 0.
srcBegin needs to be 0 in your case, but srcEnd needs to be 3.

This works:

```
a.getChars(0,3,ch,0);
```

And you need a char array with the length 3 and not 2, so change `char ch[]=new char[2]` to `char ch[]=new char[3]`

To copy only the first character into the ch array at index 1:

```
a.getChars(0,1,ch,1);
```

Comment: To make this a more useful answer, you could offer correct parameters for the current problem and add the code. As it stands, this is more of a comment. `                String a = "abc";
                char ch[] = new char[3];
                a.getChars(0,3,ch,0);`

Comment: Sorry about that! I saw that there was already a couple of answers so I thought I was too late anyways :)

Comment: I'm just trying to copy first character of string to array at index 1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are lacking calling `pw.flush()`, then something shows up. That should be the result of your program. You might have to change parameters in `String.getChars()` method according to this [Java tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_getchars.htm), as you are receiving an empty array.

```
    String a="abc";
    char ch[]=new char[2];
    a.getChars(1,2,ch,1); //Put indexes to first 2 positions to mark srcBegin, srcEnd
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out);
    pw.println(ch);
    pw.println("ABC");
    pw.println(ch);
    pw.flush();
```